# Difference between running a zero-truncated model on zero-truncated data and running a GLM on zero-truncated data

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, assumptions, zero-inflation

I apologize if this a remedial question but I am trying to determine how best to proceed with my analysis and I would appreciate if someone could explain the differences in assumptions between a zero-truncated model (zerotrunc in r) on zero-truncated data and a glm on zero-truncated data.

For context I am attempting to analyze zero-inflated data using a hurdle model. My data is a multi-year dataset evaluating a natural population of animals that breed once a year (the population was sampled each year and I excluded any animals that were sampled more than once). I am attempting to determine if a set of independent variables have any effect on the probability of individuals having offspring and if so, the mass of the offspring. The model contains the primary independent variables I am interested in plus some fixed effects such as offspring age, year, mother's age, mother's mass, and mother's mass gain rate during the period between breeding and pupping. My model is admittedly overparameterized for the sample size (n=100) but I was able to combine my independent variables into one and employ a bias reduction on the binomial portion of the hurdle model and achieve a model fit I am somewhat satisfied with (although year as a categorical fixed effect is giving me some trouble since some years are much smaller sample sizes than others); however, I just don't have enough data to run the model using the zerotrunc function in R. when I run it with glm with the zeros included I am able to fit the model, but the issue is I don't know how the differences in the assumption between the two models are impacting the likelihood of a type 1 or 2 error.

I know the zero-truncated model assumes the response **cannot** have zeros while the glm assumes that it can so the probability distributions are different; however, I'm uncertain if that makes the glm model more conservation or less conservative than the zero-truncated model. If using a GLM with the zeros excluded increases the likelihood of a type 2 error (meaning I fail to reject the null hypothesis that my independent variables are not affecting the mass of the offspring) then that would be considered a more conservative model for my research question. If it's more conservative and I find a significant effect I can work with that. If it's less conservative and I don't find a significant effect that is also something I can work with. Otherwise I will need to find a different approach to my research question if I can address it at all.

Update: I ultimately ran my model as a two part hurdle using a binary GLMM followed by a zero-truncated GLMM with year as a random effect in both models. Year as a random effect fixed my issue with sample size and was appropriate for my specific data situation; however, I do still feel that a succinct answer to this question may be useful for other people with similar analytical needs especially since hurdle models are growing in popularity among scientists looking to understand impacts on populations where thresholds often exist and ecological data is notoriously messy. If any CV mods disagree please let me know or feel free to close/delete.

Comment: Hi @Kaliber, welcome to CV. A zero-truncated model _is_ a GLM - just a particular GLM which has as its family function, a zero-truncated distribution (e.g. zero-truncated Poisson, zero-truncated Negative Binomial etc.). Perhaps if you want more statistical advice, you can provide some more information on what kind of data you have, what "conservative" means in your context, and what the desired modelling outcome is?

Comment: hello @AlexJ thank you for your response. I have added some additional details to my question to provide context as to my data and what would be considered more or less conservative.